# Can react native require a javascript module that downloaded from the internet dynamically?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to write an app that can dynamically require a javascript module that downloaded from the internet.For example,the app downloads a simple js module via react-native-fs's downloadFile function ,the js module as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

module.exports = class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello World.</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

How could I use the Hello class as a component in index.android.js file? I just want to execute the code dynamically.

As far as I konw, to use the js module, I have to require or import the js module. However, I can not require the file or import the js module(I guess I can only require the js module that bundled into the js bundle).

Does react native support this feature? I know react native can dynamically downloads js bundle from the internet. Does it support a single js file and execute the js module?

Any opinion is appreciated !

Comment: I think it's possible by using `eval`, but it's really not recommended.

Comment: @Xeijp You mean react-native-eval?
https://github.com/artemyarulin/react-native-eval